# select where string doesn't match exactly

Tags: sql, sql-like

It's my table rows:

```
++ id ---- text ++++++++++++++
-- 1  ---- '90','80,'50' -----
-- 2  ---- '30','2','1_2' --
-- 3  ---- '10_2','5_3' -----
```

as you see, `text` contains 2 types of numbers, one doesn't have underscore, and the other does.

I want to select rows which have at least one number without underscore (type 1). Something like this: (result-set)

```
++ id ---- text ++++++++++++++
-- 1  ---- '90','80,'50' -----
-- 2  ---- '30','2','1_2' --
```

(`3` is ignored)

How to do that? (I think it's possible with `NOT LIKE`, but I don't know how to write)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below query counts the number of commas in the strings, number of distinct numbers can be calculated as 1 more than the number of commas as the numbers are separated by commas, number of underscores in the string:

```
select id,
len(text) - len(replace(text,',','')) as count_of_commas,
len(text) - len(replace(text,',','')) + 1 as count_of_number,
len(text) - len(replace(text,'_','')) as count_of_underscore,
len(text) - len(replace(text,',','')) + 1 - (len(text) - len(replace(text,'_',''))) as zero_if_no_number_without_underscore_exists
from t1
```

The above query gives the following results:

[image]

Now using the logic of above query, following query can be used to get the desired result:

```
select * from t1
where len(text) - len(replace(text,',','')) + 1 - (len(text) - len(replace(text,'_',''))) != 0
```

i.e. it returns the rows where atleast one number exists without the underscore.

Comment: Thanks! It works perfect.. (Note: `LEN` doesn't exist in MySQL 5.1, it replaced with `LENGTH`...

Answer (score 2):

How long may be your numbers? Try this:

```
SELECT t1.id,t1.txt FROM t t1, t t2 WHERE t1.txt LIKE "%'__'%" AND t2.txt NOT LIKE "%\__',%"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with `LIKE`, but you can with a `RLIKE`, which uses regular expressions:

```
select * from mytable
where `text` rlike "'\d+_\d+'"
```

Comment: I think your expression will select `2` and `3`, but I want to select just `3`... (in `3`, all numbers have an underscore, but in `2`, some don't)